# onpaste event replaces text in textbox

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onpaste

I have an issue with the onpaste event in JS.
I need to copy the clipboard content into two text boxes by splitting it into half. I am using the code below:

```
function paste(){
document.getElementById("txt1").value = clipboarddata.substr(0,2);
document.getElementById("txt2").value = clipboarddata.substr(2,4);
}
```

this function is called on the `onpaste` event. The content gets pasted but after the function the entire string is again paste in the box into which the data was paste.

Can I by any chance cancel the event by using `cancelbubble` etc to cancel the event in the `paste()` function?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but here is a way of doing that for anyone that looks for this:

After you do what you have to do, You have to `return false;` This will prevent the default handler from running.

Here's a demo:

### HTML

```
<textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
<textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
```

### Javascript

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('txt1');
myElement.onpaste = function (e) {
   var pastedText = undefined;
   if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
      pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
   } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
      pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
   }
   document.getElementById("txt1").value = pastedText.substr(0, pastedText.length / 2);
   document.getElementById("txt2").value = pastedText.substr(pastedText.length / 2 + 1, pastedText.length);
   return false; // Prevent the default handler from running.
};
```

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7N6Xq/124/)</kbd>